# Creating Instances from Snapshots

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I've an f1-micro instance which I've been testing docker on created as such:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create dockerbox \
  --image container-vm-v20140731 \
  --image-project google-containers \
  --zone europe-west1-b \
  --machine-type f1-micro
```

This all works fine.

I'm now in the process of upgrading to a larger google compute engine VM. I've taken a snapshot of the fi-micro dockerbox, then used this as the Boot Source for the larger n1-standard-8 VM... this seems to create without problems until I try to ssh onto it.

via the command line:

```
$ gcloud compute --project "secure-electron-631" ssh --zone "europe-west1-b" "me@biggerbox"
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Your SSH key has not propagated to your instance yet. Try running this command again.
```

via the browser, ssh connection I get:

```
Connection Failed
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Please check that the VM is healthy and the SSH server is running.
```

I've tried multiple times but same result

I've confirmed it biggerbox is RUNNING. not sure about sshd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem seemed to stem from not detaching the micro instance from a mounted persistant disk when I took the snapshot. Detached and unmounted the PD volume and snapshotted the micro-instance again and based a new n1-standard-8 on it. Works ok now.

FYI, also handy for those troubleshooting GCE instance ssh:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-ssh-diagnostic-sh